# Encoding Card Ranks Java

Tags: java

I have to write a method called handScore that takes an array of cards as an argument and that adds up (and returns) the total score. The ranks of the cards should be encoded as I have written them, but I'm not sure how to legally encode them.

```
public class Cards {
int suit, rank;

public Cards () {
    this.suit = 0; this.rank = 0; }

public Cards (int suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit; this.rank = rank;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public static void printCard (Cards c) {
    String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
    String[] ranks = { "narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
    "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    System.out.println (ranks[c.rank] + " of " + suits[c.suit]); }

public static void printDeck (Cards[] deck) { for (int i=0; i<deck.length; i++) {
    printCard (deck[i]);
}
}

/**
 *
 * @param c
 */

public static void buildDeck(Cards c) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
        for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
            Cards[] deck = null;
            deck[index] = new Cards (suit, rank); index++; } }
}

public static void handScore(Cards[] hand) {
    spades = 3;
    hearts = 2;
    diamonds = 1;
    clubs = 0;
    ace = 1;
    jack = 11;
    queen = 12;
    king = 13;
}
```

Comment: Loop through the hand, and keep a count of the suits and the value cards.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you mean when you say "The ranks of the cards should be encoded as I have written them, but I'm not sure how to legally encode them."  Plus, different card games can have different values for the same card.  But I'll offer a suggestion or two based on what I think you might be trying to do.

One option would be to create a Card class with a getScore() method.  If this is not an option, you may want to consider a method in your class that returns a score for each card based on the rank (and suit, if suit is relevant).  So

```
public void getScore("Queen") {
    ...
```

}

would return a 12 or whatever the rank for the queen is.  You may want to use an array to store the score for each card.  I won't post more code in case this is a homework assignment, but I hope that helps.